# ¿Navegador manda error en la consola de no reconocer una función?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, formularios, google-forms

Hola compañeros tengo un código que envía datos de un formulario php a un formulario de Google. Anteriormente ya había usado el mismo código para realizar los envíos a cualquier formulario de Google y si me había funcionado correctamente. Pero ahora no entiendo porque me arroja el siguiente error la consola al intentar enviar los datos.

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
>   at postToGoogle ((index):510)
>   at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit ((index):452)

¿Podrían ayudarme a identificar cuál es el error que no me esta reconociendo la función del script?

Este es el formulario:

```
<form class=" w-md-70 w-lg-70 w-xl-60 m-auto text-center" id="form" target="_self" onsubmit="return postToGoogle();" action="">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nameField" name="entry.1859304656" placeholder="*NOMBRE" required value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailField" name="entry.78817541" placeholder="*E-MAIL" required value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telField" name="entry.746077822" placeholder="*TELÉFONO" required value="">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn mt-3" id="send">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Este es el script:

```
function postToGoogle() {
        var field1 = $("#nameField").val();
        var field2 = $("#emailField").val();
        var field3 = $("#telField").val();

        if (field1 == "") {
            alert('Por favor ingrese su nombre');
            document.getElementById("nameField").focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (field2 == "") {
            alert('Por favor ingrese un email válido');
            document.getElementById("emailField").focus();
            return false;
        }
        if (field3 == "" || field3.length > 10 || field3.length < 8) {
            alert('Por favor ingrese su teléfono');
            document.getElementById("telField").focus();
            return false;
        }




        $.ajax({
            url: "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd9HrTmyFgcWI_ONqquXQ282oHAm7bXBEhO7MYP_ah-DqGQcw/formResponse?",
            data: { "entry.1859304656": field1, "entry.78817541": field2, "entry.746077822": field3 },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (d) {
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {

                $('#success-msg').show();
                $('#form').hide();
                //setTimeout(function () {
                //window.location.href = "/";
                //}, 3000);

            }
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Y uso este para que pueda funcionar

> < script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" >< /script >

Lo he hecho anterior mente y si me funcionaba pero ahora no quiere funcionar...

Este código lo encontré aquí en stackoverflow

Comment: Ese error suele ocurrir cuando no has incluido la librería jQuery. OJO: **debes incluirla antes de usar cualquier código jQuery, si la incluyes después tendrás el error como es lógico. Y, evita los espacios en blanco en la palabra `script`, ponlo así mejor: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano, pero sigue sin funcionar le quite los espacios pero sigue mandando el error como sino estuviera cargada la librería, alguna otra solución?

Comment: La puse al final del html y en la cabecera y no funciona

Comment: Prueba poniendo la librería de jQuery directamente: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` Ponlo así tal cual en el `head` y quita la de Google.

Comment: Funcionó!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!, muchas gracias... la verdad no entiendo porque la librería de Google no quería cargar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creditos a ***A. Cedano***

Se incluye el siguiente código en el head:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Se quita el código de Google del head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```